# How to link _references.js file for an empty web application in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, projects-and-solutions, javascript-intellisense

For a normal MVC or web forms project, VS13 adds the javascript intellisense helper file named **_references.js**. How to do the same ***for a blank web application*** ? In other words, *how to manually create and link* this intellisense file to a new project? Where and how is the _references.js file linked with the project within visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project root should contain a folder called "Scripts." This "Scripts" folder is supposed to contain the "_references.js" file.

```
Enter _references.js

This file must (by default) be located in a folder at the root called /Scripts/. 
That's the naming convention. 
Any file located at /Scripts/_references.js is automatically added to global Intellisense.
```

This is the default setting. However, you can even customize the location of the _references.js file and even its name - see this [great article](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) for details (from where I quoted the above excerpt as well).